# CLIPS blocks world part 2

Tags: clips

Someone here helped me to fix my code and it works great for:

(assert (stack A B C) (stack D E F) (goal-stack D C B) (goal-stack A) (goal-stack F E))

and

(assert (stack A B C D E F) (goal-stack A B C D E F))

But for:

(assert (stack A B C) (goal-stack A B) (goal-stack C))

it just puts A onto the floor and then stops.

This is my new code:

```
(defrule move-direct
 ?stack1 <- (stack ?block1 $?bottom)
 ?stack2 <- (stack ?block2 $?goalbottom)
 (goal-stack $? ?block1 ?block2 $?goalbottom)
 =>
 (retract ?stack1 ?stack2)
 (assert (stack ?block1 ?block2 ?goalbottom))
 (assert (stack $?bottom))
 (printout t ?block1 " moved on top of " ?block2 crlf))




(defrule move-on-floor
 ?stack <- (stack ?top $?middle ?next $?bottom)
 (goal-stack $? ?next $?goalbottom)
 (not (stack $? ?next $?goalbottom))
 =>
 (retract ?stack)
 (assert (stack ?top))
 (assert (stack $?middle ?next $?bottom))
 (printout t ?top " moved on to the floor" crlf))
```

Comment: If the previous answer was correct, please mark it as solved. Otherwise make sure the contributor can help you before posing new questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CLIPS blocks world](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52683741/clips-blocks-world)